# How to create an "entity" composed of drawing shapes, labels and buttons with relative sizing and positioning in Kivy?

Tags: python, layout, kivy

I am new to Python and Kivy.  I am trying to create the display of a temperature controller (called PID). The PID is composed of:

- A light grey rectangle background;
- A black rectangle display in the upper part of the light grey background;
- Two labels in the black display to show set and current temperature; and
- Four buttons under aligned horizontally within the light grey background under the black display.

I will need to use and display four of these PID.  Is there a way to create it as one "entity or component or widget" that can be called and displayed as needed with relative sizing and positioning to automatically adjust within the window?

I managed to create it but only with fixed size and positioning

[Here is a screen shot of the PID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iNOP.png).

I tried many things, including float and relative layouts but I am not able to create the PID controller so that the components (black display, labels, buttons) are relative to the the light background and so that I can I use size_hint and pos_hint to display the PID in the windows.  Part of the problem seems to be that "rectangle" does not support size_hint and pos_hint.

Here is the basic Python code at the moment:

```
 from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
    from kivy.uix.button import Button
    from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
```

Here is the Mivy code at the moment:

```
class MainWidget(Widget):
        pass

    PID:

    <PID>:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 1, 1, .3
            Rectangle:
                size: 200, 150
                pos: 300, 200
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: 180, 80
                pos: 310, 260
                
        Widget:
            Button:
                size: "40dp", "40dp"
                pos: "310dp", "210dp"
                background_normal: "Set@1x.png"
            Button:
                size: "40dp", "40dp"
                pos: "357dp", "210dp"
                background_normal: "Reset@1x.png"
            Button:
                size: "40dp", "40dp"
                pos: "403dp", "210dp"
                background_normal: "Down@1x.png"
            Button:
                size: "40dp", "40dp"
                pos: "450dp", "210dp"
                background_normal: "Up@1x.png"
            Label:
                color: 1, 0, 0, 1
                text: "107.38"
                size: "40dp", "40dp"
                pos: "430dp", "305dp"
            Label:
                color: 0, 1, 0, 1
                text: "70.04"
                size: "40dp", "40dp"
                pos: "430dp", "270dp"
```

Thank you in advance for your time and help, very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears no one is going to answer this, I decided to build what you're describing as an exercise. Hope this works for you.

I believe for `pos_hint` to work, the widgets have to be children of either `FloatLayout` or `RelativeLayout`. You probably know this since it's pretty basic, but `pos_hint: {'x': .3, 'y': .7}` just means Kivy will place the left side of the widget at 30% of the layout width from the left side, and the bottom of the widget at 70% of the layout height from the bottom. Likewise, `size_hint: (.2, .2)` means Kivy will make the widget width size 20% of the layout width and the widget height 20% of the layout height.

So you have to create your `FloatLayout` in the python code, and then in the kv language under the parent `FloatLayout` add the children with `pos_hints` and `size_hints`. In kv language, you can set the canvas Rectangle `pos` to `self.pos` and `size` to `self.size`, and then enter the `pos_hint` and `size_hint` after (see below). Then the canvas of the widget will get it's `pos` and `size` from the `pos_hint` and `size_hint` and automatically update when the window resizes.

Python code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class PID(FloatLayout):
    pass

class PIDApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return PID()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    PIDApp().run()
```

kv language code:

```
#:kivy 2.2.0

<PID>
    Widget: # this is the grey background
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: (.5,.5,.5,1)
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        pos_hint: {'x': .3, 'y': .3}
        size_hint: (.4, .4)

    Widget: # this is the black screen
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: (0,0,0,1)
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        pos_hint: {'x': .32, 'y': .45}
        size_hint: (.36, .22)

    Label: # this is the top red label
        text: '107.38'
        color: (1,0,0,1)
        pos_hint: {'x': .55, 'y': .55}
        size_hint: (.1,.1)

    Label: # this is the bottom green label
        text: '70.04'
        color: (0,1,0,1)
        pos_hint: {'x': .55, 'y': .47}
        size_hint: (.1,.1)

    Button: # I only added the first image to the buttons, so you will need to add the others
        pos_hint: {'x': .33, 'y': .33}
        size_hint: (.07, .08)       
        Image:
            pos: self.parent.pos
            size: self.parent.size
            source: 'Set@1x.png'
            fit_mode: 'fill' # this make the image fill the button area
    Button:
        pos_hint: {'x': .42, 'y': .33}
        size_hint: (.07, .08)       
    Button:
        pos_hint: {'x': .51, 'y': .33}
        size_hint: (.07, .08)       
    Button:
        pos_hint: {'x': .60, 'y': .33}
        size_hint: (.07, .08)
```

Comment: Thank you so very much for your time and solution mishaeel!  This is exactly what I was trying to do and I now understand the concept.  THX again!